# R grid.table column heading character rotation

Tags: r, gridextra

I am attempting to use grid.table to produce an image of a table for placement in a word document using Rstudio-knitr-pandoc.  It is rather large with long column names.  The solution I would like to accomplish is rotating the column headings to 90 vertical.  Is this possible with grid.table or any other means?

I have tried

`toxinsGrob<-tableGrob(cyano.x.t,name='toxins',edits=gEdit(gPath='gpar.coltext',rot=90))
grid.draw(toxinsGrob)`

to no avail.  Suggetions?

Joel

Comment: try the packages xtable or pander and/or the knitr command `kable(table)` have a look at their documentation, I only know how to do this in latex or with html-tables using xtable, so I have no idea if it even works with word

Comment: my workaround is to edit the tables in word.  this doc only has this table that needs altering so little motivation for really looking into it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's easy with the new version of grid.table,

```
tt = ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params=list(rot=90)))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(head(iris), theme=tt)
```

[image]